# Unable to check a blank field in before trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

Hi I have built a trigger to throw error if a field is blank upon certain condition.

Since it is for large number of country i used trigger instead of validation rule.

However I tried to test it but the trigger did not throw the error.

Please find the trigger below

```
trigger TR_REMA_OPP on Opportunity (before insert,before update) {

for(Opportunity opps : trigger.new){

    if((opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'ARGENTINA' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'AUSTRALIA' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'AUSTRIA' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'BELGIUM' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'BRAZIL' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'CANADA' || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'CHINA'
         || opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'DENMARK' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'FRANCE'  ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'GERMANY' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'HONG KONG' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'INDIA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'INDONESIA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'IRELAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'IRLAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'ITALIA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'ITALY' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'JAPAN' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'KOREA (NORTH)' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'KOREA (SOUTH)' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'LAOS' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'LUXEMBOURG' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'MEXICO' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'NETHERLANDS' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'NEW CALEDONIA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'NEW ZEALAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'NICARAGUA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'NORWAY' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'PARAGUAY' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'PERU' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'PHILIPPINES' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'POLAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'PORTUGAL' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'REPUBLIC OF SAN MARINO' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'REUNION ISLAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'SINGAPORE' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'SPAIN' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'SWEDEN' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'SWITZERLAND' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'UNITED KINGDOM' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'UNITED STATES OF AMERICA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'URUGUAY'   ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'VENEZUELA' ||
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c !='VIETNAM' || 
            opps.AccountHQCountry__c != 'ZIMBABWE') && opps.Probability >= 75 && opps.Financed__c == ''){



                    opps.addError('Financed is mandatory to update');


    }
}

}
```

On the last step I also tried qpps.Financed__c.addError('this field is mandatory to update');

Stll did not worked.

opps.AccountHQCountry__c is a formula text field which will display the accounts country. Based upon the condition i set the account country to a different country to make sure the condition are met and the probability to above 75 still did not worked.

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: A few things: 1) Try putting in a few System.debug() statements to spit out the values of `AccountHQCountry__c`, `Probability` and `Financed__c`. 2) Consider changing `opps.Financed__c == ''` to `String.isBlank(opps.Financed__c)` for nulls. 3) Strongly consider storing those countries in a custom metadata instead of hardcoding those values.

Comment: @DrewKennedy Great thanks, that worked perfectly.

Comment: @DrewKennedy String.isBlank is overkill. Fields loaded from a database with no value are always `null`, never an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formulas are in a "before" update state in a "before" trigger; for new records, this will be a null value, and for updates, will be the calculated value before saving. Use an "after" trigger instead. They will be correctly calculated only in an after trigger.

Also, note that `field != A || field != B` will always be true (if the field is equal to A, it will not be equal to B, and vice versa). Use && instead.

Also, you could improve performance by simply saying:

```
Set<String> countries = new Set<String> {
  'ARGENTINA', 'AUSTRALIA', ...
};
if(!countries.contains(opps.AccountHQCountry__c)) {
  opps.addError('...');
}
```

Empty fields loaded from a database are always null, never an empty string:

```
opps.Financed__c == null
```

Probability is exposed as a decimal percentage (value / 100). You should compare against 0.75:

```
opps.Probability > 0.75
```

Comment: @ sfdcfox  The opportunity is making the finaced field required to save when the record meets the condition if I put this in after trigger how will it throw an error to user before he commits the record to database.

Comment: @SamuelRobert after triggers are not fully committed, it's only a save point about half-way through the DML operation. Adding an error here will still undo any changes.

Comment: @ sfdcfox  Sure thanks. :)

Comment: sfdcfox  I tried to implement your solution, but the system throws error even after the probability is less than 75